# Sharing music on NAS with Zune and iPod?

Tags: network-shares, nas, ipod, zune, zune-software

After being a long time iPod owner, I'm switching to the new Zune with its subscription model. I haven't bought a Zune yet but I'm planning on doing so within the next month or so.

I have approximately 40GB worth of music and my girlfriend has her iPod music library around 30GB. I've been trying to figure out how to migrate all our music off of our laptops/desktops and centralize everything on my NAS.

In sharing iPod music isn't too bad. Sharing from one machine to all is fairly easy within the iTunes player. As far as storing all the music on a NAS, again, iPods aren't too bad and imagine other systems aren't difficult. But I'm really new to the Zune and I'm beginning to run into some issues.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to store all music from our iPods and Zune subscriptions *and share music* between the iPod/Zune within the same file share on my NAS? I'm sure it's *possible* to store music on a share, but I'm not sure how iTunes and the Zune software differs.
2. Is there 3rd party software, maybe something like DoubleTwist that can sync based from NAS to multiple desktop/laptops? I've never used DoubleTwist but it's something that I found that looks *close* to being what I need. I've never quite done this myself so I'm trying to find a solution that can: a) store music on a network share; b) sync between different devices (Zune/iPod) *seamlessly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zune software is pretty awesome with letting you choose where to find music, you can specify specific folders for the Zune software to find music.  It will do it over a network, as long as you are connected...

You should be able to share iPod/Zune music back and forth as long as there is no DRM protection.  If you buy the Zune Pass, it will be DRM protected, and you won't be able to sync that with an iPod, if I'm not mistaken... *the Zune software will not sync with iPods though!*

For something like DoubleTwist, look at **[Sync Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52)**, free.  I would set up a sync pair, and just run it once in a while to sync music between your NAS and your various machines...I've used it to backup folders over the LAN (Local Area Network), and it works great!

> SyncToy 2.1 is a free application that synchronizes files and folders between locations. Typical uses include sharing files, such as photos, with other computers and creating backup copies of files and folders.

Comment: +1 for SyncToy. I had no idea it existed but it seems like the perfect complement for all Windows OSes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RoboCopy (or [Hobocopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hobocopy/) if source-files are in-use) to keep directories in sync.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is not a forum -- so if you have a problem, it's better to [ask a new question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) instead. I took out those parts from your answer again — you can still view them when you click the "edited" link above my icon. Please make sure to reference this question though.